# Is it very safe to short volatility with a small position?

Tags: stocks, volatility

The derivatives of volatility, such as VXX, incur significant long-term holding losses, making shorting appear profitable. However, situations similar to the 2018 'Volmageddon' could easily lead to a total account blowout. But considering that there's a cap on volatility, with the VIX index peaking at 100 (since the S&P 500 cannot drop to zero), if I were to use only a very small position, say 5%, even if the VIX rises from the current 13 to 100, I wouldn't face a blowout. Is there any flaw in my thinking?

Comment: It is not correct that the VIX inherently cannot exceed 100. It is not simply related to a percentage change in the S&P 500. Rather, the VIX is a measure of expected *logarithmic* changes and has no inherent upper bound.

Comment: If you are short VIX and it rises from 13 to 100, you will lose 7X what you put in (for every 13 you invest, you'll have to pay 100). I would consider that a "blowout".

Comment: Not definitive, but take a look at [this article](https://seekingalpha.com/article/4307027-how-to-short-vix-without-blowing-up-your-entire-portfolio-backtesting-hedged-short-vxx). If you don't understand the risks involved then it's probably best to stay away from shorting volatility.

Comment: It's always dangerous to try to invest in something whe you don't even know what the value represents. There is no upside boundary in the VIX whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes there is a flaw.**

VIX can exceed 100%.
(consider the October 28-29 crash in 1929 --> resulted in a two-day loss of 24% in the Dow Jones Industrials Average, with two-week realized volatility rocketing to 127%.)

Should a inverted Vol-fund (e.g. XIV) liquidate this could lead to a disloaction, increasing implied volatility further, despite realized vol being still lower.

Vol-trading is risky .